# How to make azure webjob run continuously and call the public static function without automatic trigger

Tags: c#, azure, azure-webjobs

I am developing a azure webjob which should run continuously. I have a public static function. I want this function to be automatically triggered without any queue. Right now i am  using while(true) to run continuously. Is there any other way to do this?

Please find below my code

```
   static void Main()
    {
        var host = new JobHost();
        host.Call(typeof(Functions).GetMethod("ProcessMethod"));
        // The following code ensures that the WebJob will be running continuously
        host.RunAndBlock();
    }

[NoAutomaticTriggerAttribute]
public static void ProcessMethod(TextWriter log)
{
    while (true)
    {
        try
        {
            log.WriteLine("There are {0} pending requests", pendings.Count);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            log.WriteLine("Error occurred in processing pending altapay requests. Error : {0}", ex.Message);
        }
        Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(3));
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: You can put it on a schedule that runs every 3 minutes.

Comment: You dont need the whole JobHost thing you have there, you can simply call ProcessMethod from Main and use Console.WriteLine to log.

Comment: Hi, I have just shown a simple example in ProcessMethod to log. Other than logging, the ProcessMethod does other processes ie. calling database, update sql table , etc.,

Comment: @AmitApple What if you want to have a cancellation token to allow a graceful shutdown? Is it needed then? (Acknowledging support for this may have been added after your comment)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

These steps will get you to what you want:

1. Change your method to async
2. await the sleep
3. use host.CallAsync() instead of host.Call()

I converted your code to reflect the steps below.

```
static void Main()
{
    var host = new JobHost();
    host.CallAsync(typeof(Functions).GetMethod("ProcessMethod"));
    // The following code ensures that the WebJob will be running continuously
    host.RunAndBlock();
}

[NoAutomaticTriggerAttribute]
public static async Task ProcessMethod(TextWriter log)
{
    while (true)
    {
        try
        {
            log.WriteLine("There are {0} pending requests", pendings.Count);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            log.WriteLine("Error occurred in processing pending altapay requests. Error : {0}", ex.Message);
        }
        await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(3));
    }
}
```

Comment: Is Thread.Sleep generally a problem in WebJobs e.g. in static (non async) functions? Thanks!

Comment: If it's a scheduled or manual webjob you shoud get the task returned from CallAsync and call Wait() on it.

Comment: System.ArgumentNullException: 'Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: method'

Comment: What is the purpose of `NoAutomaticTriggerAttribute`? What happens if you remove it?

Answer (score 19):

Use the Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Timers, see https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-extensions/blob/master/src/ExtensionsSample/Samples/TimerSamples.cs to create a trigger that uses a TimeSpan or Crontab instruction to fire the method.

Add Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Timers from NuGet to your project.

```
public static void ProcessMethod(TextWriter log)
```

becomes

```
public static void ProcessMethod([TimerTrigger("00:05:00",RunOnStartup = true)] TimerInfo timerInfo, TextWriter log)
```

for five minute triggers (using TimeSpan string)

You will need ensure your Program.cs Main sets up the config to use timers as follows:

```
static void Main()
    {
        JobHostConfiguration config = new JobHostConfiguration();
        config.UseTimers();

        var host = new JobHost(config);

        // The following code ensures that the WebJob will be running continuously
        host.RunAndBlock();
    }
```

Comment: I do this, but it terminates after some days. My method is async Task ProcessTimer([TimerTrigger("00:01:00")]...). I run in Basic plan and Always On.

Comment: System.ArgumentNullException: 'Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: method'